# Loop Partial View with different model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my ViewModel i've got a list.

For each value of this list i want to render the same partial view, with the values of the listitem.

With my usage of it, it uses the view every time with the same Model.

Here my example

```
@foreach (Date i in Model.Dates)
        {
        <div class="d-inline-block badge-light align-content-between" style="padding: 20px; border-radius: 40px;">

            <label class="form-check-label float-left" style="padding:20px;">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="">

            </label>
            <i class="fas fa-info-circle float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalView"></i>
            <partial name="_DateModalPartial" model="context.Dates.Find(i.Id)" />
            

            <div style="line-height:0.3; padding: 20px;">
                <p class="text-center">@String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", i.StartingDate)</p>
                <p class="text-center">-</p>
                <p class="text-center">@String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", i.EndingDate)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this, create a partial view and don't use loop in partial. Like this:

```
    <div class="d-inline-block badge-light align-content-between" style="padding: 20px; border-radius: 40px;">

        <label class="form-check-label float-left" style="padding:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="">

        </label>
        <i class="fas fa-info-circle float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalView"></i>
        <partial name="_DateModalPartial" model="context.Dates.Find(i.Id)" />
        

        <div style="line-height:0.3; padding: 20px;">
            <p class="text-center">@String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", i.StartingDate)</p>
            <p class="text-center">-</p>
            <p class="text-center">@String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", i.EndingDate)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

put you values using 1 model in partial, then use your loop to loop that partial view in your main page.

Comment: I'm not sure how to combine this with my project.

I want to do the following : The model of the view includes a list, where i wan't to display them. Each item got a button, which opens a popup with additional information. So i want do add the partial view for each item so i can popup for each item a window with different information

Comment: I know, I tell you just create a partial View with a model that you want. then in partial view set values to that model. Then, loop many partially with many models in your page.